# How to transfer files from Linux to android using the command line. (Linux/Fedora26)?

Tags: linux, mtp

When I plug in my Galaxy S4 into my computer running `Fedora 26`, I am able to easily write files to the SD card by dragging and dropping them onto my phone's SD card in `nautilus`, the file browser. However, if I try to copy over the same file using `cp`, I am told that the opperation is not supported.

I've tried to ssh into the phone by using such apps as `SSHDroid`, but I always receive an error telling my that I don't have the necessary permissions when I try to write to my phone.

### Steps To Reproduce:

1. Plug Android into computer with usb cable.
2. Open command prompt and attempt to file copy a file: `cp screenshot.png /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp\:host\=%5Busb%3A001%2C015%5D/Card/fromComputer/`. This outputs the following error message:

   `cp: cannot create regular file '/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C015%5D/Card/fromComputer/screenshot.png': Operation not supported`
3. Open `nautilus` and navigate to the mounted Android phone's sd card. Copy and paste the desired file onto the card. The opperation will be successful.

Comment: Have you tried FTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your phone:

1. Open Settings > About Phone
2. Click on Build Number 7 times
3. Go to Settings > Developer Options
4. Enable Developer Options and enable Debug mode on USB

On your computer:

1. Install ADB on your computer. You may refer to [this guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/guide-installing-adb-fastboot-linux-adb-t3478678), although it isn't for Fedora, the steps should be similar.
2. Use adb push/pull to copy to/from your phone. To transfer a file to your phone, use `adb push filename.extnsion /sdcard/0/` and substitute the path to the sdcard accordingly for your device.