# mac address randomization on NON-rooted Android 8.1 phone for both wifi and mobile data

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-network, xiaomi, 8.1-oreo, mac-address

I am trying to force my box to

(up to date as of posting, NOT rooted Xiomi Redmi Note 5 with Android 8.1.0 OPM1.17 with security patch 2018-09-01., kernel 4.4.78perf+, gui is MIUI v10.0.2.)

randomize mac address by default before connecting to any network on both wifi/wlan and "mobile data" connection.

How do I achieve this, please?

Comment: autistic, on the following site they mention random MAC for Android 8 very shortly https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-mac-randomization I have no Andoird 8 anymore so I can not test it, but you can look under developer options.
Source: https://support.google.com/fi/thread/4601390/how-can-i-turn-off-mac-randomization-in-android-8-1-generic-tablet?hl=en I hope it helps.

Comment: I do not know whether that would work on v8.1, but the following works with v11: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58507/how-can-i-randomize-my-mac-address-every-time-my-wifi-is-turned-on/241760#241760